# User-icon at top left corner in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons

Is there some way to get rid of the 'user (home) icon' in the top-left corner of my Ubuntu 20.04 screen?  Clicking on it just duplicates what I get when opening the Files management application which I keep in the Dock since I use it so frequently. Having recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04, I don't mind the Trash icon near the top-left corner but this new icon seems redundant.  Is there some added advantage to it that I haven't discovered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**GUI Option**

1. Launch the "Extensions" app.
2. Click on the settings (gear) icon next to "Desktop Icons".
3. The Desktop Icons configuration dialog will appear.

   Note: If you don't see "Extensions" app, you can launch the Desktop Icons configuration dialog using the command:

   ```
   gnome-extensions prefs desktop-icons@csoriano
   ```
4. On the dialog, toggle the "Show the personal folder in the desktop" switch.

[image]

**Command-line Option**

1. Open a terminal
2. Enter the following command

   ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, P J Singh!  I used the command line option and it worked just as you described.  Done.  Thanks so much!